# How to fire a Textfield listener in JavaFX?

Tags: java, listener

In Java, I'm trying to fire a Textfield listener.

The only solution I've found is to use setText with a space:

```
txt.setText(" ");
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Details:

```
TextField txt = new TextField();
        txt.setPromptText("Search");
        txt.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldVal,Object newVal) {
               //...to do
            }
        };
txt.setText(" "); //Firing the listener
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `txt.setText(" ");` will not work when a single space is enterer in the textfield already. Therefore it would also be an unreliable way of fireing a change event

Answer (score 5):

*Invoking a stored listener reference*

You could record a reference to the listener and invoke that whenever you want, for example:

```
TextField txt = new TextField();
txt.setPromptText("Search");

ChangeListener<String> txtListener =
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                System.out.println(
                        "Search text updated to: " + newValue
                );

txt.textProperty().addListener(
        txtListener
);

txtListener.changed(
        txt.textProperty(),
        null,
        "frobozz"
);
```

This will output "`Search text updated to: frobozz`".  What I don't much like about this is that it doesn't carry a lot of semantic meaning and the text hasn't really changed.

*Alternate approach*

An alternate approach is to have a function which is named related to your application and invoke that whenever you want either inside or outside the listener.  I prefer this alternate approach.

```
txt.textProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> search(newValue)
);
search(null);

. . .

private void search(String searchText) {
    System.out.println(
            "Search result for: " + searchText
    );
}
```

This will output: "`Search result for: null`".

Note: this answer used [Java 8 code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: I believe the last function should be `private void search(String newValue)` or the println should read `System.out.println("Search result for: " + searchText);`

Comment: Thanks Jack, I fixed the parameter name usage to be searchText instead of newValue.